# JSONProvider transform elements to attributes (cxf)

Tags: json, cxf, jax-rs

We are building a REST service with CXF where we send and receive data in both JSON and XML

In the JSON version we dont want to bother our clients with using the '@' notation for attributes and using the "attributesToElements" parameter on the JsonProvider (org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider) ensures we dont send these attributes to the client that way.

However when receiving the data back (same format) the JsonProvider is unable to UnMarshall the received data correctly because it doesnt realize the attribute values are attributes (and treats them as elements instead).

In [issue 3475](http://org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProviderhttps://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3475) of the cxf bug tracker this problem is acknowledged and marked resolved because its a a problem to handle on the receiving end. there is being referred to using the transformation feature of the Jsonprovider, however i cant seem to get it to work.

i tried to configure the transform in beans.xml with several variations like:

```
<property name="inTransformElements">
   <map>
      <entry key="fieldname" value="@fieldname"/>
      <entry key="fieldname" value="{@}fieldname"/> 
   </map>
</property>
```

but with no succes.

Is it possible with the cxf JsonProvider to transform elements back to attributes?
And if so how?

Answer (score 0):

JUst to understand the question,

XML shown above is the output

```
<property name="inTransformElements">
   <map>
      <entry key="fieldname" value="@fieldname"/>
      <entry key="fieldname" value="{@}fieldname"/> 
   </map>
</property>
```

Did you try with latest version of CXF?

Comment: this xml are attempts to configure the jsonprovider (in beans.xml)